# Scraping Vocabulary using Selenium and parsing to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv, web-scraping

There is this little program that goes to a vocabulary, print all the words from that page and then click at the button to go to the next page and print again all the vocabulary on that page.

I used a loop to repeat the process and loop through all the words spread on multiple pages.

```
#Create csv
outfile = open("Vocab.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)


#Define the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['rating'])



PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


driver.get("https://sq.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:Shqip&pagefrom=agall%C3%ABk#mw-pages")


for x in range(3):
        rating_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mw-pages > div > div > div > ul"))
        )
        rating=rating_element.text
        print(rating)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "faqja pasardhëse"))
        )
        element.click() 
        
        
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([rating],columns=['rating'])  
        df = df.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
```

The code itself works perfectly fine, however when I tried to implement the function of parsing all the data into a DataFrame, I only get an empty Csv File. I'm trying to have only one column with the thousands of words.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each word to append to the column:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.common.exceptions
import os
import pandas as pd

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

# Define the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['rating'])

driver.get("https://sq.m.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Kategoria:Shqip&pagefrom=agall%C3%ABk#mw-pages")

for x in range(200):
    rating_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mw-pages > div > div > div > ul"))
    )
    rating = rating_element.text

    for word in rating.split('\n'):
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([word], columns=['rating'])
        df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "faqja pasardhëse"))
        )
        element.click()
        
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        break

print(df)
df.to_csv('word_list.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

#### Outputs

```
      rating
0    agallëk
1       agar
2      agave
3       agde
4     ageshë
..       ...
595    ankim
596  ankimor
597  ankohem
598    ankoj
599   ankojë

[600 rows x 1 columns]
```

#### Edit

Added the option to write to a file.

Comment: The rest was unchanged, but i'll edit it in

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error '''' WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home''' even though I gave the right path

Comment: Try to pass your path like this: `PATH=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"` to ignore escape codes. And if you're using my code don't forget to remove `os.getcwd() +`

Comment: the problem is that I have to loop through 200 pages, get all the words and parse the to the dataframe. I am getting the following error when in the loop I write 200. https://ibb.co/BgNzCLV

Comment: This is happening after 187 iteration because there is no more new pages to look, so you cant find the next page anchor element. There are 37,490 words, 200 per page, so we get 188 pages to check only.

Comment: You will have to look for this exception and break the for loop, else you cant scrap the last page. I'll edit this.

Comment: thank you. The only problem is that  the letter "ë" is being parsed in the Csv file as "Ã«"

Comment: If you used the right encoding probable the csv file is right. Try to check it in the notepad. I saw here that when opening the csv in excel this change happens, so it is an excel problem.